# Getting a Container inside an Expanded inside a Row to expand vertically to fit the space available in the Row

Tags: flutter, layout, widget, containers

I have a row containing four Expanded widgets. Its code looks as follows:

```
Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: (Text(
                    lessonData.language,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: (Text(
                    lessonData.cEFRLevelName,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: (Text(
                    lessonData.lessonTopic,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                child: Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  color: Colors.blueGrey,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  child: (
                      Text(
                    lessonData.lessonHeading,
                    style: const TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  )),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
```

The resulting display is unsatisfactory if any of the texts in the Containers inside the Expanded widgets are forced to wrap. As in this image:

[Click here to display an image of my problem when text has wrapped in one Container but not in the other three.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUDP0.png)

[This image shows something like what I'd like the Row to look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzR1A.png)

I simply can't get the Container widgets containing text without any wrap to expand out to the height of the row.

Among other candidate solutions, I've tried setting the height to double.infinity and double.maxFinite, setting Constraints in the Containers to Constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(). All these options either do nothing or generate an error on hot reload.

I'm reluctant to try an IntrinsicHeight widget because I'm warned that it's very hungry.

I'd be very grateful for any solution and/or comment you might have!

TIA

Jaime

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: i can't Understand What you want to say?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUDP0.png you Exactly want this ?

Comment: What I get is the picture shown in the linked image. I want the three leftmost Containers to expand vertically to take on the same height as the right-hand Container (which has grown because the text inside it has wrapped). The four Containers together should look like a blue-grey rectangle.

Comment: Can you share any image that describe exactly What you want

Comment: Well ... not so easily ... after all, I can't achieve it.

Comment: I'll try and manipulate the image of what I'm not happy with and post it.

Comment: sorry to say but i can't understand what you want

Comment: I've added a picture of what I'd like the Row to look like!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want, I may have a suggestion. It's more of a workaround, but you can move the `Container` with the colored backgroud up a level and remove each other `Container`, making the new `Container` the parent of the whole `Row`: I put the code in a DartPad, and this is how it  looks. [image: example]

Just an excerpt of the code:

```
Container(color: Colors.red,child: Row(
            children: [
              Expanded(...),
              Expanded(...),
              //and so on...
```

This works only on an aesthetic level: each `Text` will still get resized, but you won't notice.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks promising! I'll try it out!

Comment: I've tried it out.  Not only  does it work, but it looks more logical than my work.

Comment: Thanks, but it's just that I faced the same issue in the past...and again, it won't work if you plan to put something else in the Expanded, like a Button or something that needs to intercept taps/clicks

Comment: That's a good tip!  I'm about to start entering check boxes, etc. to the set of containers underneath the Row shown here. I'll keep it in mind!